# How to edit embedded images in a Visual Studio project

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, resources, embedded-resource

I have a Windows Forms project. For some controls the property "Image" has value System.Drawing.Bitmap (not some file from the resources). I need to make some changes to the images. Is there a way I can get them out as a separate files and edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of Visual Studio you are working with, but here's a quickie for Visual Studio 2010. For standard controls, those images are hosted in the project resource file or as a local resource.

Project resource file: you can edit it via projects settings -> *Resources*. Right-click the image and choose "Open with".

Local resource: Actually the images are not stored in the filesystem, but rather added to the resx file of your form (e.g. MainForm.resx) as a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded serialized representation. If you know how to, you could Base64-decode that string, save the result in a flatfile and name it correctly (you must know the image type for that).

Maybe there's a more comfortable way, but that's what I'd try in the first place.
See also: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html (I haven't tried it, though).

Comment: I tried soft at that link earlier, but it doesn't work. Deserialization seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: local resources, then? maybe just put it in here : http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple (at least in Visual Studio 2008): just open the resx file of your form (i.e. Form1.resx), and it lists all Local resource images. Right-click on the image you want to edit, and select "Export To File...". Done.